# C function to modify inode?

Tags: c, linux, inode

I was learning how linux file system works and I came across the concept of inodes. I have written a C program to read a particular inode and print its contents.

Now I wan't to modify the contents of inode from my C code. I know this could break the filesystem if something goes wrong but still I want to try it.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How did you read a particular inode and printed its contents? I guess you would have parsed the filesystem metadata like superblock, root inode for that.

Comment: @Fazlin: Yes I did the same thing

Comment: Once you have parsed the filesystem metadata to read the contents of inode, what problem you face in writing it back? You will know the offset from which you have read the particular inode. Modify the local struct inode and write it back at the same offset.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access what is called the "meta" information of the drive - the information about the information on the drive - not the normal information. To do that, you need to open the drive itself rather than any file or directory inside the drive.

If you're talking i-nodes, then you're on Linux and the ext filesystem, so the drive name will be something like `/dev/sdb`. Be careful: this is the whole disk, NOT one partition/volume/slice within it. That might be called `/dev/sdb2` or something - different types of Linux call them different things.

Once you have the partition open, you can treat it just like a (very large!) file: a succession of bytes that coincidentally happen to be arranged as sectors on the hard disk. You can seek to any position and read the data there. If you want to overwrite it, you can - but as you say:

## You may completely destroy the data on your hard disk!

Perhaps mount a USB stick (with nothing important on it) and experiment on that? And make ***VERY*** sure that you open ITS name and not your main disk's name!

Comment: So you are saying I need to find out the actual hard disk block where this inode is stored and then rewrite that particular block? And yes I was going to try it out on a separate USB disk.

Comment: Or create a file containing a FS => http://askubuntu.com/questions/85977/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-mount-it-as-a-filesystem

Comment: @Harry That's exactly what I'm saying. And to know the correct i-node, you need to parse the directory tree to get the file's root i-node, and from there to go up the arrays, arrays-of-arrays, and arrays-of-arrays-of-arrays to get to the i-node of interest. You basically have to grok the entire file system structure...

Comment: @Garf365 I like the way you think...!

Comment: @JohnBurger: Thanks for the answer..looks like it is not that easy to modify an inode still I am going to try it with approach mentioned by Garf365! Also If you can provide some pseudo code it will be very helpful! Thanks

Comment: Pseudo-code would take pages. I have a very visual memory, so I found the best way to work was to find diagrams of the structure of i-nodes, and directories, and... But sorry, I don't have a single reference for these. It's more a collected library of knowledge.

Comment: @John Ok, let's say I opened a device for writing and I want to edit the metadata of a file that I know its inode number. How do I know where to write?